# How to send source code - very common question

Tags: c#

I wanted to know what part of the project I need to copy for my USB for example in order to get the source code of the project. Do I need to copy the whole folder? Or do I need only the .sln file? Or..?because I've tried to copy the .sln file and when I try to open it with the other computer, it says that it can't open it for some reason.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the whole folder. Also, if you have third party references, you'll need those assemblies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the entire folder. The source code of a c# visual studio project is the .sln, .csproj, .cs, etc and also the external dependencies, dll:s, etc.

If you view the .sln file in a text editor you can see the references it has. The open up the project files (.csproj) listed in the .sln and see the files they reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy each file because there are many dependencies, like forms, windows, etc.

You need whole folder..

Answer (score 0):

If you **just** need the source code, you could copy the whole folder. If you're looking for the code, look for the C# (.cs) files *within* the folder, and open them with notepad++ or something later on.

If you want the project, just copy the whole project folder over.